# Is it a bad design to have a structure where one class contains list of another class and vice versa

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I was working on design of User Role Management system. In this system a user can have many roles and a role can have many users. It is one to many relationship in between both user and role. I was thinking of a design to establish this relationship as:

```
Class User
{

  List<Role>
}

Class Role
{
List<User>
}
```

My question is, Is this a bad design.If yes what should be the recommended way to establish relationship.

Regards

Comment: The only downside to this design is having to make sure that the lists are in sync (which can be a pain when it comes to multi-threaded environments)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand any previous accusations of a bad design. This is a typical design to map many-to-many relationships. In particular if you use Entity Framework, you get relationships like this all the time.
You can even have a self-reference, why not?

```
class Person
{
    List<Person> Friends;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not that bad or uncommon to do this in the context of child and parent objects.

```
Class User
{    
  List<Role> Children;
}

Class Role
{
  List<User> Parents;
}
```

This way you always know the linking from parents to childs.

An example would be the XMLNode Class in the .NET Framework.

It has ChildNodes and ParentNode properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would consider this bad design because now you have two lists to maintain, assuming this even compiles with cross referencing.

You are much better to either create a joining object that something else holds a list of (A class that has both user and a role).

Or just pick the one that makes the most sense and then apply some querying on that when need to find all users with a specific role. I.E

```
 myListOfUsers.Where(user => user.Roles.Contains(something));
```

Comment: Cross referencing only causes compilation errors if the classes are in separate assemblies.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - Thanks, I added that just incase of that edge case

Comment: @Sayse - Can you provide an example where compiling code in this scenario won't be possible? If I am not wrong, circular reference issue would come up before compiler can even try to compile the code.

Comment: @VijayGill - Create a dll that contains a `Role` class with the user list, then try to reference that role class again in the program that contains the User class

Comment: @Sayse - That should work too because both the "User" classes will be in different namespaces. If, due to bad design, the namespaces are same, then compiler will try to use the class in the same project which may lead to compiler error if two classes differ in constructor/method signatures. But that is totally different kind of bad design. What the OP is doing is still not a bad design, IMHO.

Comment: @VijayGill - I mean only using the one user class. My issue with the OP design is it is going to get very error prone to make sure that both lists stay up to date and accurate. What if a user wants to take on a new role or remove one? That means you must make sure to update 2 lists.